# Visual source safe replacement

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

Can someone offer please a free software that will be able to replace VSS 2005 for me? I can't afford to pay for it.

Thanks.

Comment: the `2005` at the end of that should tell you that you shouldn't be using it. You need to be more specific about your requirements, but most ppl are onto Git or Mercurial nowadays for source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [lots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software) - which one you should use depends on the specifics of how you work.

At the moment my personal favourite is [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) which is [distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) - there is a very good introduction to how using distributed version control works here - [Hg Init: a Mercurial tutorial](http://hginit.com/).

I personally find that distributed version control works really well for me, but if you are looking for something that behaves a little more like VSS then you might want to look into alternatives such as [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) which is widely used and very mature.

Answer (score 0):

ok there are a ton.  I would suggest using the googly and doing a search for something like open source source control.  Take a look [here](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=open+source+source+control+visual+studio&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=g1g-j2&aql=&oq=).

Answer (score 0):

Although, there are plenty, I would recommend you to try SVN, it's a centralized SVN and comes very close to Visual Source Safe, I see that the recommended answer recommends Mercurial, but it looks like SVN will work out for anybody that want to move over. We did a massive migration a year back from VSS to SVN without any issues.